# Visual Studio 2015 cross platform addition dependencies doesn't work?

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

I'm try to include an shared library (.so) in a Android cross platform dynamic library, i put the name of the "so" dll in the project configuration under "Addition Dependencies"

But when compile the "linker" doesn't found my library.

I tested to add the "path" in "Additional Library Directories" and "Shared Library Path" but nothing, same error.

Works ONLY if i put the entire path with so name library on "Additional Dependencies" but the compiled "so" (opened with a text reader) reports the ENTIRE PATH for the dll and in runtime it call C:.. in android device!?!.

[image: project configuration]

[image: Linker configuration]

Someone have same issue ?